# Napili Community landing on error pages in Microsoft Edge that are real

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, error, napili, microsoft-edge

I'm having this issue where when users navigate to certain pages on my napili community site, they land on our standard error page. There is nothing wrong with the URL though. If the user refreshes the page, it's fine. This only seems to be happening in the Microsoft Edge browser. Has anyone come across something like this?

Comment: Are these pages all of a specific type, e.g. lightning components rather than record detail or record list pages?

Comment: Yes, they are lightning component pages.